# Different area between Query raster/vector tool and v.to.db

Tags: grass-gis

I found a discrepancy between the select GUI tool "Query raster/vector" and v.to.db, and I do not know why. I attached the pictures.

1. First image (image 1) show that the attribute "area_value" (in hectares, calculate with v.to.db and populate the table) differ from "hectares" above (I do not know how this is calculate).

[image: Image 1]

2. The second image (image 2) show an import discrepancy between the "area_value" attribute of this polygon and the one showed in image 1. It is the same polygon or almost the same, you can see that the "hectares" attribute value is close image 1.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Could you post the v.to.db command you ran?